# How to get current year in a Nunjucks template within Apostrophe CMS

Tags: datetime, apostrophe-cms, nunjucks

I am in the process of adding a copyright line to the footer of a website that I have been working on and I cannot find the best way to get the current dynamically into the footer so I never have to set it again. I have tried multiple things, including a global setting that can be accessed from anywhere, but nothing has worked.

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write an ApostropheCMS [nunjucks helper function](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/core-concepts/working-with-templates/nunjucks-helper-functions). See those docs for the general issues around this. Your specific function could look like:

```
self.addHelpers({
  thisYear: function() {
    return new Date().getFullYear();
  }
});
```

If you put that in `construct` of a module of your own, let's say it's called `helpers`, then you can call it in Nunjucks as `{{ apos.helpers.thisYear() }}`.

These are very handy, just remember they cannot do any async work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   I have added the code above to a module and my template and I am getting the following error: `Unable to call apos["helpers"]["thisYear"], which is undefined or falsey`

Comment: Is the module's alias option set to "helpers"?

Comment: The code that I am using is below. It is also worth adding that my server won't run when I add this module to the `app.js` file.

This is the contents of index.js file within the `helpers` module directory:

`module.exports = {        
   extend: 'apostrophe-module',        
   label: 'Helpers',
   alias: 'helpers',
   construct: function(self, options, callback) {
      self.addHelpers({
         thisYear: function() {
            return new Date().getFullYear();
         }
      });
   }        
};`

Comment: You chose to include a callback for construct, but never invoked it. Remove the callback argument completely.

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thank you for your help.